# Social buttons on top of each other rather than next to each other in Drupal

Tags: css, drupal, button, html

I am struggling with a CSS issue. I want to display a Google +1 button next to ShareThis buttons (I am using Drupal).

For some reason, Drupal adds a panel searator CSS class:

[image]

I tried to modify my CSS file as following:

```
.panel-separator { display: none; }
```

but it only produced this:

[image]

There is enough space to the right of the ShareThis buttons to display the Google +1 buttons. But, the buttons are stacked on top of each other.

How do I get the button to align horizontally? Thanks.

**Update**

I have set a lot of width and I also added `float: left;`:

```
.GYPO_social_buttons {
    padding-top: 91px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

.GYPO_share_this {
    width: 90px;
}

.GYPO_google_plus_one {
    width: 40px;
}
```

Here is the enclosing `div` according to firebug (I am using Firefox):

[image]

**Update II**

Woops, my bad. I have now set the `float: left;` on the button themselves rather than the enclosing `div` and the issue is solved. Thanks !!!

```
.GYPO_share_this {
    width: 90px;
    float: left;
}

.GYPO_google_plus_one {
    width: 40px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give enough width to the container div, that is holding these icons. After that you can float these icons by giving  `float: left;` . The reason why Google +1 is moving down is because the container div doesn't have enough width to accommodate this next to mail icon.

Comment: I have tried your recommendations, but it did not solve the issue. See the update in my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the portion of html and css you are providing it is a little bit difficult to find out what would be the best way to do this. The question is what generates the break. It could be that the parent element is not wide enough to and the +1 needs to be below. In that case you can simply change the width. It could also be that there is css that generates a break (e.g. display: block and no float for on eof the elements) In that case you might try to change that to display: inline or a float: left for the buttons. There might be a clear somewhere in there which would cause the float to break (although it doesnt look like a clear on the image)

I suppose there are more possibilities than that...

Answer (score 0):

I need to see more of your code. If you have tried to make your container larger to hold all of the icons and that didn't work, I would guess it was another element forcing the icon to the next line. Without more code, all I can do is make a guess...

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation once. Here's what solved my problem:

**You can also choose the "style" setting on the region and choose "No markup at all". This will remove the panel separator.**

For more info: https://www.drupal.org/node/579020#comment-8163459